# EF Core One to one relation where both sides are optional but one property is not nullable

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I have a model that looks like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long? BarId { get; set; }
    public virtual Bar? Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Foo? Foo { get; set;}
    
    // This would be easy, but I want a one to one relation
    // public virtual ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; } = new HashSet<Foo>();
}
```

I now want to configure a one to one relationship.
The tricky part is that `Bar.Id` may have a value that is not present in the `Foo.BarId` column.

So this must be possible

**Foo**

| Id | BarId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | null |

**Bar**

| Id |
| --- |
| 3 |
| 4 (no Foo.BarId that matches) |

How can I achieve this using DataAnnotations or Fluent configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try this

```
public class Foo
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public long? BarId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(BarId))]
    [InverseProperty("Foo")]
    public virtual Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Bar")]
    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set;}

}
```

but if you use net5+ you maybe don't need any attributes or fluent Apis